# Android convert Synchronous request to asynchronous using internal library Interface Callback

Tags: android, asynchronous, interface, retrofit, rx-java

I am using .aar library in my app.
It has one Interface for the Network delegation which I need to overwrite.

```
ApiResponse executeApiCall(String url, HTTPMethod method, String params)
```

I am using Retrofit for the network calls. I need to convert the Synchronous call to USE asynchronous.

```
@Override
public ApiResponse executeApiCall(String url, HTTPMethod method, String params) {
    ApiResponse apiResponse;

    try {
        // Synchronous Call
        Call<String> call = RestClient.get().getStringResponse(url, method, params);
        Response<String> response = call.execute();
        apiResponse = new ApiResponse(response.code(), response.body());
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        apiResponse = new ApiResponse();
    }

    return apiResponse;
}
```

**Now I am stuck in how to use Asynchronous call within the Network Interface I must overwrite.**

```
@Override
public ApiResponse executeApiCall(String url, HTTPMethod method, String params) {
    ApiResponse apiResponse;

    // Asynchronous Call
    Call<String> call = RestClient.get().getStringResponse(url, method, params);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<String> call, @NotNull Response<String> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                apiResponse = new ApiResponse(response.code(), response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<String> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
            apiResponse = new ApiResponse();
        }
    });

    return apiResponse;
}
```

I can not change the Network delegation interface. I must overwrite it and I need to use retrofit Asynchronous.

Your feedback is most appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: Instead of using the aar library interface, can you just use the Retrofit async call directly in your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some code on a different stack overflow thread.  Here is how you could use the code to achieve what you are looking for.

Here is the class

```
public abstract class AsyncRunnable<T> {
    protected abstract void run(AtomicReference<T> notifier);

    protected final void finish(AtomicReference<T> notifier, T result) {
        synchronized (notifier) {
            notifier.set(result);
            notifier.notify();
        }
    }

    public static <T> T wait(AsyncRunnable<T> runnable) {
        final AtomicReference<T> notifier = new AtomicReference<>();

        // run the asynchronous code
        runnable.run(notifier);

        // wait for the asynchronous code to finish
        synchronized (notifier) {
            while (notifier.get() == null) {
                try {
                    notifier.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
            }
        }

        // return the result of the asynchronous code
        return notifier.get();
    }
}
```

You can use it like this

```
  ApiResponse result = AsyncRunnable.wait(new AsyncRunnable<ApiResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void run(final AtomicReference<String> notifier) {
            // here goes your async code, e.g.:
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     Call<String> call = 
                     RestClient.get().getStringResponse(url, method, params);
                     call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<String> call, 
                       
                         @NotNull 
                         Response<String> response) {
                          
                             if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                 apiResponse = new 
                                              ApiResponse(response.code(), 
                                 response.body());
                                 finish(notifier, apiResponse);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<String> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
         apiResponse = new ApiResponse();
         finish(notifier, apiResponse);
    }
});

                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

We wait for the response to come from the callback and notify the AsyncRunnable class.

Comment: I had to convert the ApiResponse apiResponse;             
to  ( final ApiResponse[] apiResponse = new ApiResponse[1]; )        
and   ApiResponse result = AsyncRunnable.wait(new AsyncRunnable<ApiResponse>() {  
   ... 
to ( final ApiResponse[] result = {AsyncRunnable.wait(new AsyncRunnable<ApiResponse>() { ... )      
Then in the  apiResponse = new ApiResponse(response.code() ...  
to ( apiResponse[0] = ... )

Answer (score 0):

I feel you, I had a similar problem with a library that needed to do heavy work (non-UI) on the UI thread. Yep, sounds like a psycopath's lib. Coroutines `runBlocking` are your friend. I realize that you're asking for a rx-java solution, but can't beat coroutines for this.

```
/**
 * You can edit, run, and share this code. 
 * play.kotlinlang.org 
 */
    import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking


fun main() {
    
    val apiResponse = executeApiCall()    
    
    println(apiResponse) // prints "response"
    println("goodbye, world!!!")
}

/**
 * Synchronous function that waits for coroutine to finish
 */ 
fun executeApiCall():String {
    
    return runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO){
     
        retrofitCall()
    
    }
  
    
}

/**
 * Method that invokes Retrofit call in the background.
 */ 
suspend fun retrofitCall():String{
    
//  RestClient.get() ...
    return "response"
}
```

Note that if you call `executeApiCall` from UI thread you still will block the UI thread. So possible you need something like `lifecycleScope.launch{executeApiCall() }` if you're inside an activity or fragment (gradle dependency `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.1.0`), or `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { executeApiCall() }`  otherwise.